# Nodemailer working in local, but not on lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, nodemailer

Nodemailer is sending emails when I run on local, but not on lambda. Surprisingly, none of the solutions for questions similar to this on SO are working for me. One of the questions also suggested to make the sendEmail function in nodemailer asynchronous and await it as it doesn't wait for it to complete execution on AWS like it does on local.

Below is my code that has the mailing logic (Please refer to the lines where I have commented with the labels [1] and [2]) :

```js
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import SMTPTransport = require('nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport');
import * as Tracer from 'tracer';
import {Transport} from 'common-models/transport';
import {MailObject} from 'common-models/mailObject';

import * as Mail from 'nodemailer';
import EmailTemplates = require('swig-email-templates');



export class MailHelper {
    private logLevel = process.env.TRACER_LEVEL || 'debug';
    private smtpOptions: SMTPTransport.Options;
    private transporter: nodemailer.Transporter;
    private templates: EmailTemplates;
    private logger: Tracer.Tracer.Logger = Tracer.colorConsole({
        level: this.logLevel
    });


    constructor(transport: Transport) {
        this.smtpOptions = {
                host: transport.host,
                port: transport.port,
                secure: transport.secure,
                tls: transport.tls,
                auth: {
                    user: transport.auth.user,
                    pass: transport.auth.password
                }
            }
        }

    connect(): Promise < boolean > {
        console.log(`Inside connect`);
        return new Promise < boolean > (async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                this.transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport(this.smtpOptions)
                resolve(true);
            } catch (error) {
                this.logger.fatal(error);
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    }

    async sendMail(body: MailObject): Promise < string > { //<-----[1] made this asynchronous

        console.log(`[bodymail][value]: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`)
        const senderAddress: Mail.Address = {
            address: body.from.emailAddress,
            name: body.from.name ? body.from.name : ''
        }


        const recipientAddress: Mail.Address = {
            address: body.to.emailAddress,
            name: body.to.name ? body.to.name : ''
        }

        const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
            from: senderAddress,
            to: recipientAddress,
            subject: body.subject,
            text: body.text ? body.text : undefined,
            html: body.html ? body.html : undefined,
            amp: body.html ? body.html : undefined
        }
        console.log(`[mail options][value]: ${JSON.stringify(mailOptions)}`)

        return new Promise<any> (async(resolve, reject) => {
            if (!this.transporter) {
                this.logger.warn(`Transporter not intitialized. Use connect method`);
                reject(`Transporter not initialized. Use connect method`);
            }
            console.log(`Inside the promise of sendMail`);
                 this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(async value => { //<--- [2] also using then to await for the result
                    console.log(`[sentMail][value]: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
                resolve(value);
            }).catch(error => {
                this.logger.fatal(error);
                reject(error);
            })
        })
    }

    public sendMailFromHTML(body: MailObject): Promise < string > {
        return new Promise < string > (async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Inside the promise of sendMailFromHTML`);
            this.sendMail(body).then((value: string) => {
                resolve(value);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            })
        })
    }

    public sendMailFromTemplate(body: MailObject, values: {}): Promise < string > {
        this.templates = new EmailTemplates();

        return new Promise < string > ((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Inside promise of sendMailFromTemplate`);
            this.templates.render(body.template ? body.template : '', values, (err, html, text, subject) => {
                if (err) {
                    this.logger.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    body.subject = subject ? subject : body.subject;
                    body.html = html;
                    body.text = text;
                    this.sendMail(body).then((value: string) => {
                        resolve(value);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
this.transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport(this.smtpOptions)
```

To:

```
this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(this.smtpOptions)
```

This fixed my SMTP issues for a project hosted on Vercel. The behaviour was similar, I was unable to send emails from the production but I had no issues on my local environment.